# How to make the statusbar and navigationbar same in ios7?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I know there is all sorts of ways to make the status bar and navigation bar same in ios 7.But my problem is i am working in xcode 4.2.In that i did like this to make this happen in viewdidLoad,

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
{
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
else
{
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

but when i am working on build  in iphone having ios 7.0.2 the status bar remains transparent.Can anybody help me in pointing out where i am going wrong ?

Comment: I see that you're calling prefersStatusBarHidden, but have you actually implemented this method on your view controller? If you want the status bar hidden, you need to implement this method and have it return YES.

Comment: @Greg i did it.As its obvious to return yes on that i didnt mention it in my question,But the problem is it is not still working in my phone which has the newest version of ios

Comment: What is the value of UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance in your Info.plist? If you're using prefersStatusBarHidden, you'll want that to be true.